# Disabling scrolling in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome makes the page flickr ...

Tags: internet-explorer, scroll

I made a sidebar menu to a web page, that slides from the right and pushes the whole page to the left. So, in order to make it closest to the native mobile apps with similar sidebar menus - I had to disable the scrolling of the main content. So, I did it with this code:

```
/* remember the current scroll position */
self.pageScrolledTo = $(window).scrollTop();

/* and build a listener for the scroll event */
$(document).on('scroll',function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  window.scrollTo(0, self.pageScrolledTo);
});
```

And the problem is that in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome - when I show the sidebar, and attempt to scroll the page - the whole page flickers. It's like it scrolls for a moment, and then it goes back to the same position.
On Firefox it's OK - the page stands still.

Can you help me with this? ...

And one last thing: if I make the html and/or body tags with overflow: hidden; - on Internet Explorer and Firefox the scrollbars disappear, but it calculates the right distance of elements from the old right edge ... as for some elements the scrollbars are still there ... ?? ...